# h:graphicImage not reRender

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu, graphicimage

i have a jsf file where i have selectOneMenu and a h:graphicImage.Now the problem is when i send onchange request through selectOneMenu  and want to reRender the h:graphicImage and want to show and hide boolean in action bean.But not work properly. Actully first i investigate it very carefully that when i send action through selectOneMenu the boolean value set correctly in bean but not set the reRender value properly.If i refresh page then it work properly.Anyone who i can solve it if i want to refresh page on  selectOneMenu  actionlistener then how i refresh page.My code is here for more detail

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="stageListID" value="#{mnpBean.stageList.defaultValue}" >
<f:selectItems  value="#{mnpBean.stageList.values}"/>
<a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{mnpAction.onStageListChangeAction}" reRender="addBtn1" oncomplete="resetViewConfigs();"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

code for grphic image

```
<h:graphicImage id="addBtn1"  url=""  rendered="#{mnpBean.showAddButton}" style="cursor:pointer">
<a4j:support id="addRowBtn1" event="onclick"  actionListener="#{mnpAction.addMultiNoRingFence}"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```

bean code here

```
public void onStageListChangeAction(ActionEvent ae) {
mnpBean = getMNPBean();
if ("10".equals(mnpBean.getStatusList().getDefaultValue()) &&       "010".equals(mnpBean.getStageList().getDefaultValue())) {
 mnpBean.setShowAddButton(false);         
 }else{
 mnpBean.setShowAddButton(true);         
 }

}
```

Any helping regarding this appreciate

Comment: @BalusC please suggest solution here

Comment: `@nickname` comment-replies don't work if the person in question hasn't edited/commented the post beforehand Just wait until they see the question :)

Comment: @BalusC ok now got it :) anyway thanks for this also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do :

1. Wrap your `<h:graphicImage/>` in a container like `<h:panelGrid/>`

   ```
   <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" layout="none" id="imageContainer">
    <h:graphicImage id="addBtn1"  url=""  rendered="#{mnpBean.showAddButton}" style="cursor:pointer">
       <a4j:support id="addRowBtn1" event="onclick"  actionListener="#{mnpAction.addMultiNoRingFence}"/>
    </h:graphicImage> 
   <a4j:outputPanel/>
   ```
2. Use the id of the container as the target of the `reRender`

   ```
   <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{mnpAction.onStageListChangeAction}" reRender="imageContainer" oncomplete="resetViewConfigs();"/>
   ```

For the reason why the issue is happening the first place, see explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325002/1530938)